# PHP: going through an non ordered index multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have the following array:

```
$users
: array = 
  0: array = 
    0: object(Person) = 
      strName: string = John
      strLastName: string = Smith
      strAge: string = 19
    1: object(Person) = 
      strName: string = Jean
      strLastName: string = Newton
      strAge: string = 22
  1: array = 
    0: object(Person)= 
      strName: string = John
      strLastName: string = Smith
      strAge: string = 19
    1: object(Person) = 
      strName: string = Jean
      strLastName: string = Newton
      strAge: string = 22
  2: array = 
    0: object(Person) = 
      strName: string = Martin
      strLastName: string = Marin
      strAge: string = 25
```

In order to get rid of the duplicates I’ve done:

```
$users = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $users)));
```

And I get:

```
$users
: array = 
  0: array = 
    0: object(Person) = 
      strName: string = John
      strLastName: string = Smith
      strAge: string = 19  
    1: object(Person) = 
      strName: string = Jean
      strLastName: string = Newton
      strAge: string = 22  
  1: array = 
    0: object(Person) = 
      strName: string = Martin
      strLastName: string = Marin                                                                                                        
      strAge: string = 25
```

Now I have to get the info the array contains. 
I’m doing:

```
$i=0;
foreach ($users as $u)
{
  echo $u [$i]->getName()); 
.
.
  $i++;
 }
```

But I’m not printing all the elements of the array, $u [2] is NULL.

What I’m I doing wrong?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nested arrays: you need nested loops.

```
foreach ($users as $ulist) {
    foreach ($ulist as $u) {
        echo $u->getName(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$i=0;
foreach ($users as $u)
{
  while ($u [$i] != NULL ){
echo $u [$i]->getName(); 
.
.
  $i++;
}
$i=0
 }
```

u tried to circle, but didnt reset the $i

more precise :

Array call

```
0 0
0 1
1 2   << does not exist   => $u [2] = Null
1 3
```